# Creating PDFs in C++ that handle RTL languages and complex scripts

Tags: c++, pdf, arabic, right-to-left

Does anyone know of a good API, usable from C++, for creating PDFs with RTL languages such as Arabic and Hebrew as well as complex scripts such as Thai and Devanagari? We are presently using Tracker's PDF API which is excellent but it doesn't handle anything other than LTR scripts and it seems that RTL support is not really a priority for them as this support has been promised for almost 2 years and does not seem to be forthcoming.

Answer (score 1):

If a commercial Windows-only library is a valid option, you could try with [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/). The library provides a custom API for creating or editing PDF files. You should be able to set any kind of text in a [text object](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Developer_Documentation.htm#Amyuni_PDF_Creator_for_NET/Amyuni_PDFCreator_IacObject/properties/IacObject_Properties.htm) if you wrap it first as unicode in a [variant structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms221627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
If your application already supports printing using Windows GDI, you could re-use this code and try instead with [Amyuni PDF Converter](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfconverter/).This is a Microsoft-certified virtual printer driver that generates PDF files as output and that can be fully controlled from the printing application.

For Amyuni PDF Converter, there are two ways of using it from C++, you can either use a C++ header file that is provided with the library, or you can use it as a COM class that provides the same features. More details can be found in the [documentation](http://www.amyuni.com/WebHelp/Amyuni_Document_Converter/Introduction.htm).

The library is provided with sample code for C#, VB.Net and C++. Here is a summarized version of one of the samples:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CDIntf450.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "CDIntf450.lib")

#define AMYUNI_PRINTER          "My PDF Converter"
#define AMYUNI_LICENSE          "Amyuni Developer Evaluation"
#define AMYUNI_ACTIVATION_CODE  "0ABCCD...567B3"

//Get a handle to Amyuni PDF Converter
HANDLE hPrinter = DriverInit(AMYUNI_PRINTER);
if(hDC == NULL){ /* error handling */ }

//Set the Amyuni PDF Converter as the default printer
CDISetDefaultPrinter ( hPrinter );

//Configure the path for the output file
SetFileNameOptions ( hPrinter, NoPrompt | UseFileName );
SetDefaultFileName (hPrinter,  _T("c:\\temp\\PrintSomeThing.pdf") );

// Activate your license key
EnablePrinter ( hPrinter, AMYUNI_LICENSE, AMYUNI_ACTIVATION_CODE);

HDC hDC = CreateDC( "WINSPOOL" , AMYUNI_PRINTER, NULL, NULL);
if(hDC == NULL){ /* error handling */ }

DOCINFO di;
::ZeroMemory (&di, sizeof(DOCINFO));
di.cbSize = sizeof(DOCINFO);
di.lpszDocName = _T("myDocTitle");
StartDoc(hDC, &di);
StartPage(hDC);

//Print something
TextOutW(hDC, 200, 200, L"هذا هو اختبار"), lstrlenW (L"هذا هو اختبار")));
TextOut(hDC, 0, 400, _T("My PDF App"), lstrlen (_T("My PDF App")));
EndPage(hDC);
EndDoc(hDC);

//Clean Up
DeleteDC(hDC);
RestoreDefaultPrinter( hPrinter );
SetFileNameOptions ( hPrinter, 0 );
DriverEnd( hPrinter );
```

*Disclaimer 1: I currently work for Amyuni Technologies.*
*Disclaimer 2: The piece of text in Arabic on the sample code was obtained from Google Translate, so I apologize in advance if it turns out to be nonsense.*

Comment: Thanks - a commercial library is OK. Can you point me to some C++ examples showing how to create a PDF file from scratch by using your PDF Converter in conjunction with GDI calls?